# How to add jpg files in drawable folder with different densities in android studio 3.5?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I am using Android 3.5 version. I added the jpg file in the drawable folder. When i inspect the code, it shows warning

> "Images defined in density-independent drawable folder"

I think I have to add images in different densities drawable folders, How to do it in **Android studio 3.5 version**.
Thanks.

Comment: use .png file .

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple drawable folder for different density
[See this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUFxe.png)
Bonus tip: [Android icon reference chart](https://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/)